# Jsreport Malformed URI error when rendering Async

Tags: pdf, stream, jsreport

Since I am sending lots of data with the request, I have to use renderAsync to use POST. When the stream came back, I use the following JS code to open it

```
 jsreport.renderAsync(request).then(function(arrayBuffer) {
 window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + arrayBuffer
)};);
```

But then the error showed. Is there alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

```
<script>
    jsreport.renderAsync(request).then(function(response) {
        var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(response);
        var i = uInt8Array.length;
        var binaryString = new Array(i);
        while (i--)
        {
            binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
        }
        var data = binaryString.join('');
        var base64 = window.btoa(data);

        window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + base64);    
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You rock sir. Another great thing about jsreport is that you are always there to give perfect support for it